# Present small viewController

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, viewcontroller, cgpoint

Problem State: I've two viewController

1. parentViewController (375 * 667)
2. childViewController  (300 * 667)

and i want to present childViewController at Axis (75 * 0) as shown below

[image]

childViewController is show on this IBAction

```
@IBAction func btnShowVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cvc") as? childViewController
    self.present(newVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But it stretches itself like

[image]

can anyOne help me to tackle it?
Thanks

Comment: I think using simple subview would be better, if you want use viewcontroller then maybe try search for popover presentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: image here]
You can try in this way.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as? ChildViewController
            view.addSubview((newVC?.view)!)
        newVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x:75,y:0,width:view.frame.size.width-75,height:view.frame.size.height)
        newVC?.view.autoresizingMask = \[.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight\]


        newVC?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: If you want to add child controller then tap on child button.

Comment: The idea is corect but the code is not. You are missing the addChildViewController call.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you setting the frame of your ViewController? If you are using autolayout you will need to set constraints to make the ViewController look how you want it to. If you want to do it programatically you can set the frame somewhere for example in the code that you posted above you could do this:

```
@IBAction func btnShowVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cvc") as? childViewController
   newVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 0, width: 300, height: 667)
   self.present(newVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Its Giving this error:

Value of type 'childViewController?' has no member 'frame'

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, I forgot to add view in the call.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `preferredContentSize` property will solve your problem, Please try out below code snippet

```
newVC?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 667)
```